# Injecting Javascript in iframe using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, iframe, automated-tests

I am a novice in selenium. I want to hit a url, search for all the iframes and in every iframe, I want to inject a Javascript code. So how would I do that. So far, I have come up with basic selenium code but do not know how to inject JS.

```
public class Poc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.sss.org/");

        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
        for(WebElement element:elements) {
            System.out.println(element.getAttribute("id"));
        }
        driver.close();
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual url ? Is it sss.org ? Btw, why do you want to inject JS into the page ? Maybe there is an alternate solution for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

To inject code into each `iframe` you first have to switch to it

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
for(WebElement element:elements) {
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo.frame(element);
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("alert('hello world');");
    }
    System.out.println(element.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JavascriptExecutor for writing javascript code in selenium

Example code for you is

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click ME"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('attr', '10')",element);
```

Comment: Can you please explain whats happening in the 3rd line. Thanks